# How to keep a Python TCP listener application running?

Tags: python, pycharm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, stomp

I'm trying to make a Python program that will run on AWS (deployed via Elastic Beanstalk) that listens to a [STOMP](https://stomp.github.io) queue (a simple text based protocol over TCP). I'm using the [stomp.py](https://github.com/jasonrbriggs/stomp.py) library, [docs here](http://jasonrbriggs.github.io/stomp.py/index.html).

Here's the program, I'm running it with the PyCharm 'Run application' feature:

```
# PyPI imports
import stomp

# TODO: TESTING ONLY, REMOVE WHEN DONE!
import time


def main():
    '''Starts the STOMP listener.'''

    print('Running main function')

    # See the following example for the template this file was based on:
    # http://jasonrbriggs.github.io/stomp.py/quickstart.html
    conn = stomp.Connection([('example.com', 61613)],
                            auto_decode=False)
    conn.set_listener('print', stomp.PrintingListener())
    conn.start()
    conn.connect(username = 'username', passcode = 'password', wait=False)

    conn.subscribe(destination='/destination',
                   id=1,
                   ack='auto')

    time.sleep(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It works nicely, printing out the queue messages, but only for 30 seconds, then it stops running and outputs:
`Process finished with exit code 0`

If you comment out the `sleep` function it runs the main function, then immediately finishes the process.

But if you write it out in the Python interpreter it continues to print out the queue messages indefinitely.

**How do I get the program to keep running indefinitely from the PyCharm 'Run application' option? Or will AWS Elastic Beanstalk take care of that when I figure out how to deploy the program?**

*I'm quite rusty with Python, and new to deploying actual Python apps, so apologies if this an obvious question/answer.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an infinite while loop

```
def main():
    '''Starts the STOMP listener.'''

    print('Running main function')

    # See the following example for the template this file was based on:
    # http://jasonrbriggs.github.io/stomp.py/quickstart.html
    conn = stomp.Connection([('example.com', 61613)],
                            auto_decode=False)
    conn.set_listener('print', stomp.PrintingListener())
    conn.start()
    conn.connect(username = 'username', passcode = 'password', wait=False)

    conn.subscribe(destination='/destination',
                   id=1,
                   ack='auto')

    while True:
        time.sleep(30)
```

The while loop will run, your program will sleep for 30 seconds, the while loop will run again and then the program will sleep again for 30 seconds. This process will continue infinitely as there is no condition to terminate the loop

Comment: Interesting technique, couple of questions: (1) Would that infinite loop not eat up CPU resources? (2) This doesn't really feel like the Python best practice approach, is it?

Comment: No it wouldn't because you're not doing any cpu intensive work in the body of the loop...you're just pausing the application

Comment: Okay, I guess that's true. How do frameworks like Flask and Django keep their processes running? If they even have long running processes I guess.

Comment: Django is a web framework and not a server. so everything about the web server process is handled by whatever web server you decide to use not by django. django has threads but those threads don't run infinitely, there's always a timeout if not all django web apps would be very annoying :)

Comment: python's `manage.py runserver` uses WSGI under the hood and unfortunately i don't have in-depth knowledge about how WSGI servers work